# Connection is not available to refresh token on Azure Login

Tags: android, adal

**My Problem**

I am using azure login in my android application.I did all the process but still i get the "**Connection is not available to refresh token ver:1.13.1**" error everytime.Help could be greatly appreciated thanks.

**My Code**

```
 mAuthContext = new AuthenticationContext(LoginActivity.this, "https://login.windows.net/"+authorityUrl, true);
 mAuthContext.acquireToken(
            LoginActivity.this,
            clientId,
            clientId,
            redirectUri,
            PromptBehavior.Always,
            new AuthenticationCallback<AuthenticationResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onError(Exception e) {
                 }

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(AuthenticationResult result) {
                    android.util.Log.v("Azure", "Successfully obtained token, still need to validate");
              });
```

**My CatLog**

```
11-08 17:01:53.871 5530-5530/com.mypackage V/AcquireTokenRequest: 2017-11-08 11:31:53-d8594e3c-d905-4b75-ab1c-ddb32c60592b-Sending async task from thread:5530 ver:1.13.1
11-08 17:01:53.878 5530-6499/com.mypackage V/AcquireTokenRequest: 2017-11-08 11:31:53-d8594e3c-d905-4b75-ab1c-ddb32c60592b-Running task in thread:6499 ver:1.13.1
11-08 17:01:53.896 5530-6499/com.mypackage V/AcquireTokenRequest: 2017-11-08 11:31:53-d8594e3c-d905-4b75-ab1c-ddb32c60592b-Start validating authority ver:1.13.1
11-08 17:01:53.899 5530-6499/com.mypackage V/AcquireTokenRequest: 2017-11-08 11:31:53-d8594e3c-d905-4b75-ab1c-ddb32c60592b-The passed in authority is valid. ver:1.13.1
11-08 17:01:53.900 5530-6499/com.mypackage V/BrokerProxy: 2017-11-08 11:31:53-d8594e3c-d905-4b75-ab1c-ddb32c60592b-Broker auth is turned off or no valid broker is available on the device, cannot switch to broker. ver:1.13.1
11-08 17:01:53.903 5530-6499/com.mypackage D/AcquireTokenRequest: Trying to acquire token interactively.
11-08 17:01:53.919 5530-6499/com.mypackage W/HttpWebRequest: DEVICE_CONNECTION_IS_NOT_AVAILABLE:2017-11-08 11:31:53-d8594e3c-d905-4b75-ab1c-ddb32c60592b-Connection is not available to refresh token ver:1.13.1 
11-08 17:01:53.921 5530-5530/com.mypackage E/Azure: Error getting token: com.microsoft.aad.adal.AuthenticationException: Connection is not available to refresh token
```

Comment: Have you checked internet permission has given in manifest file?

Comment: yes its there .